# How to bubble up Exceptions from inside async/await functions in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, express

Assume an Express route that makes a call to Mongoose and has to be `async` so it can await on the `mongoose.find()`. Also assume we are receiving XML but we have to change it to JSON, and that also needs to be `async` so I can call await inside of it.

If I do this:

```
app.post('/ams', async (req, res) => {
try {
    xml2js.parseString(xml, async (err, json) => {
        if (err) {
           throw new XMLException();
        }


        // assume many more clauses here that can throw exceptions
        
        res.status(200);
        res.send("Data saved")

    });

} catch(err) {
    if (err instanceof XML2JSException) {
        res.status(400);
        message = "Malformed XML error: " + err;
        res.send(message);
    }
}
}
```

The server hangs forever. I'm assuming the `async/await` means that the server hits a timeout before something concludes.

If I put this:

```
res.status(200);
res.send("Data saved")
```

on the line before the `catch()`, then that is returned, but it is the only thing every returned. The client gets a 200, even if an `XMLException` is thrown.

I can see the `XMLException` throw in the console, but I cannot get a 400 to send back. I cannot get anything I that catch block to execute in a way that communicates the response to the client.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In this case there does not appear to be a reason to throw at all. Anyway, the exception will result in a failed promise being returned and this failed promise is.. *ignored*. See https://itnext.io/error-handling-with-async-await-in-js-26c3f20bc06a (the `await rejecting_promise` is what will re-raise the exception in the caller, yet in the original code the parsing promise is never waited upon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell, there is no way to propagate an error from the `xml2js.parseString()` callback up to the higher code because that parent function has already exited and returned.  This is how plain callbacks work with asynchronous code.

To understand the problem here, you have to follow the code flow for `xml2js.parseString()` in your function.  If you instrumented it like this:

```
app.post('/ams', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("1");
        xml2js.parseString(xml, async (err, json) => {
            console.log("2");
            if (err) {
                throw new XMLException();
            }

            // assume many more clauses here that can throw exceptions

            res.status(200);
            res.send("Data saved")

        });
        console.log("3");
    } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof XML2JSException) {
            res.status(400);
            message = "Malformed XML error: " + err;
            res.send(message);
        }
    }
    console.log("4");
});
```

Then, you would see this in the logs:

```
1    // about to call xml2js.parseString()
3    // after the call to xml2js.parseString()
4    // function about to exit
2    // callback called last after function returned
```

The outer function has finished and returned BEFORE your callback has been called.  This is because `xml2js.parseString()` is asynchronous and non-blocking.  That means that calling it just initiates the operation and then it immediately returns and the rest of your function continues to execute.  It works in the background and some time later, it posts an event to the Javascript event queue and when the interpreter is done with whatever else it was doing, it will pick up that event and call the callback.

The callback will get called with an almost empty call stack.  So, you can't use traditional `try/catch` exceptions with these plain, asynchronous callbacks.  Instead, you must either handle the error inside the callback or call some function from within the callback to handle the error for you.

When you try to throw inside that plain, asynchronous callback, the exception just goes back into the event handler that triggered the completion of the asynchronous operation and no further because there's nothing else on the call stack.  Your `try/catch` you show in your code cannot catch that exception.  In fact, no other code can catch that exception - only code within the exception.

This is not a great way to write code, but nodejs survived with it for many years (by not using `throw` in these circumstances).  However, this is why promises were invented and when used with the newer language features `async/await`, they provide a cleaner way to do things.

And, fortunately in this circumstance `xml2js.parseString()` has a promise interface already.

So, you can do this:

```
app.post('/ams', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // get the xml data from somewhere
        const json = await xml2js.parseString(xml);
        // do something with json here
        res.send("Data saved");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).send("Malformed XML error: " + err.message);
    }
});
```

With the `xml2js.parseString()` interface, if you do NOT pass it a callback, it will return a promise instead that resolves to the final value or rejects with an error.  This is not something all asynchronous interfaces can do, but is fairly common these days if the interface had the older style callback originally and then they want to now support promises.  Newer interfaces are generally just built with only promise-based interfaces.  Anyway, per [the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js-parser#new-promises-usage), this interface will return a promise if you don't pass a callback.

You can then use `await` with that promise that the function returns.  If the promise resolves, the `await` will retrieve the resolved value of the promise.  If the promise rejects, because you awaiting the rejection will be caught by the try/catch.  FYI, you can also use `.then()` and `.catch()` with the promise, but in many cases, `async` and `await` are simpler so that's what I've shown here.

So, in this code, if there is invalid XML, then the promise that `xml2js.parseString()` returns will reject and control flow will go to the `catch` block where you can handle the error.

If you want to capture only the `xml2js.parseString()` error separately from other exceptions that could occur elsewhere in your code, you can put a `try/catch` around just it (though this code didn't show anything else that would likely throw an exception so I didn't add another `try/catch`).  In fact, this form of `try/catch` can be used pretty much like you would normally use it with synchronous code.  You can throw up to a higher level of `try/catch` too.

---

A few other notes, many people who first start programming with asynchronous operations try to just put `await` in front of anything asynchronous and hope that it solves their problem.  `await` only does anything useful when you `await` a promise so your asynchronous function must return a promise that resolves/rejects when the asynchronous operation is complete for the `await` to do anything useful.

It is also possible to take a plain callback asynchronous function that does not have a promise interface and wrap a promise interface around it.  You pretty much never want to mix promise interface functions with plain callback asynchronous operations because error handling and propagation is a nightmare with a mixed model.  So, sometimes you have to "promisify" an older interface so you can use promises with it.  In most cases, you can do that with `util.promisify()` built into the util library in nodejs.  Fortunately, since promises and `async/await` are the modern and easier way to do asynchronous things, most newer asynchronous interfaces in the nodejs world come with promise interfaces already.

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing exceptions inside the callback function. So you cant expect the catch block of the router to receive it.

One way to handle this is by using *util.promisify.*

```
try{
const util = require('util');
const parseString = util.promisify(xml2js.parseString);
let json = await parsestring(xml);
}catch(err)
{
...
}
```